# Docker-compose multi project variable setup

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

Does anyone have a good solution on how to handle this?

I'm using docker compose to locally develop on a suite of apps that have the following containers:

Front-end A

Back-end A

Front-end B

Back-end B

Front-end C

Back-end C

Generally devs will need 1-2 of the front-ends and 1-3 of the backends all running locally (the apps work together in different ways). I want to create an easy way to start up whichever apps you need with minimal effort.

Here's what I've considered:

Option 1: Run all 6 containers every time - I want to avoid this in case they end up having to debug or deal with a broken container that they aren't even using at that time.

Option 2: Simple control file that determines which containers run, you comment out the ones you don't need for example this would bring up FE-A, BE-A and BE-C.  When you run it, it generates a docker-compose file on the fly to only run what you need. Complicated to set up but this is my favorite option.

```
Front-end A
Back-end A
#Front-end B
#Back-end B
#Front-end C
Back-end C
```

Option 3: docker-compose arguments where you give it a list of apps to run. I don't like the idea of having to give a bunch of long arguments though.

Any brilliant ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a single `docker-compose.yml` file because your devs can just set up whatever environment variables they need in a `.env` and then run something like `docker compose up -d servicefea servicebea servicebec` or whatever the service names are to just launch those services.

If you know the combinations they might use, you could also simplify it further using a `Makefile`. So you could have a single command for Team A that needs FE-A BE-A and BE-C something like this:

```
runteama:
  docker compose up -d servicefea servicebea servicebec

runteamc:
  docker compose up -d servicefec servicebec
```

Then the team just has to run `make runteama` or `make runteamc` or whatever, and the command will be called without needing to comment out anything.